# I wish to return the value a deque entry. Why is it of type "Void"?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2015, deque

I have create a deque below in a class myClass{}:

```
std:deque<UINT8*>myDeque;
```

I create a UINT8 pointer

```
UINT8* up = new rx[20];
```

I push it on:

```
myDeque.push_back(up);
```

Now in sum function I wish to return an entry:

```
UINT8* myClass::somefuntion()
{
  return(myDeque.pop_front());
}

         ^
```

I get an error at the caret complaining that I cannot convert a void* to
a `UINT8*`, but I don't understand how it thinks I'm trying to convert that

What is the proper way to pass/return an entry to the deque I have created?

By the way, this is using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 in a MFC C++ project where I have included:

`#include <deque>`

Comment: "What additional thing should I do to make this work?" – you should read the documentation for `std::deque`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answerable by reading the documentation.

Comment: `std::deque::pop_front` does not return the front value. use `front()` to get it and then `pop_front()`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Please don't answer questions in comments. If you want to answer the question, **answer** the question.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::deque::pop_front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front) does not return the element that you pop, it returns `void`.  Trying to return that void return which

```
return(myDeque.pop_front());
```

does gives you the illegal conversion error.  What you need to do is store the pointer into a temporary variable with `front`, call `pop_front`, and then return the pointer.

```
UINT8* myClass::somefuntion()
{   
  UINT8* temp = myDeque.front()
  myDeque.pop_front();
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: I see. You are saying that the member function pop_front() is an action only. First use of deque. My bad. I thought that pop_front() did both.

Comment: @MichaelMurdock Yes it is an action only.  If you are evr not sure what a function does exactly you can always look it up on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 2):

`std::deque` interface [provides separate functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) for removing and viewing last and first elements:

- `std::deque::front()` returns first element.
- `std::deque::back()` returns last  element.

And to remove them you need to call `pop_x` methods:

- `std::deque::pop_front()` removes first element but returns nothing.
- `std::deque::pop_back()` removes last element  but returns nothing.